# Как показать два разных значения из друх разных словарей (в боте дискорда)?

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py

вобщем, делаю я код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks
from time import time, localtime

user_counter = {}

user_kolvo = {}


msg = 'Статистика:\n'


client = commands.Bot( command_prefix = '-')



@tasks.loop(seconds=20)
async def timer_notify():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    cur_time = localtime(time())
    my_channel = client.get_channel(734611425368211457)
    for user_id,counter in user_counter.items():
        user = client.get_user(user_id)
        global msg
        msg = msg+' >> ' + user.name + ': ' + str(counter) + ' подходов' + ' | ' + str(kolvo) + ' раз' + '\n'
    await my_channel.send(msg)
    msg = 'Статистика:\n'
```

И я столкнулась с проблемой, что в строке `msg = msg+' >> ' + user.name + ': ' + str(counter) + ' подходов' + ' | ' + str(user_kolvo.values()) + ' раз' + '\n'` я не могу показать и str(counter) и str(kolvo) потому что работаю только в одном словаре (я же не могу написать `for user_id,counter in user_counter.items() and user_id,kolvo in user_kolvo.items()`

Comment: Можно сделать цикл в цикле, в чем проблема

Comment: Можно узнать `kolvo` с помощью `user_kolvo[user_id]` либо наоборот итерироваться по `kolvo`, узнавая `counter`

Comment: а что хранится в 'каунтер' и 'колво' ? одно число ? может там список подойдёт ? в [0] будет каунтер а в [1] колво